# as_array() method don't work in multiple results

Tags: php, mysql, database, orm

I'm using [idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm)  as an ORM library and the method as_array() doesn't work with multiple rows.

$p = $db->find_many()->as_array();

it gives me this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find_many() on a non-object in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the idiorm documentation:

> Any method chain that ends in find_many() will return an array of ORM
>   class instances, one for each row matched by your query. If no rows
>   were found, an empty array will be returned.

So essentially you are trying to call a method on an array, which is not an object, and thus the fatal error. What you need to do if you want to have your rows as arrays, is to loop through each of the `find_many()` array items and convert them to array with separate `as_array()` calls. Or, use the http://lt.php.net/array_map function.

Answer (score 0):

`on a non-object` in this case means the `$db` object hasn't been initialised. Check that you're properly initialising the variable with a call like `$db = new ORM;`.

Comment: I initialized it correctly , and the method "as_array()" works fine with find_one()->as_array() , the problem is in the multiple rows results.

Comment: I see, it's just the error message suggests that it's trying to find a member function called `find_many` on an object that in fact isn't an object. Since the `find_many` function is only called on the `$db` object that would suggest it's not initialised, or at least not an object at that point in your code.